# how to create a column that only gets the matching value from another sheet in EXCEL

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, vlookup

i would like to create an extra column in sheet one which displays a character (for example G) after it finds the matching values from sheet 2.below are two screen shots i have taken for all your conveniences.

[image: sheet1]

[image: sheet2]

please note,in sheet 1 i have marked two rows with identical bs_cd 6374 which matches the bs_cd 6374 in sheet 2 also.what i want is to have a character G in sheet 1 under column G.

thanks in advance

Comment: you can fill the new column with a simple `VLOOKUP`

Comment: can you solve this for me?would appreciate it.

Comment: feel free to mark my answer as your solution if it helped you

Comment: it did help me to some extent.i tired the following vlookup formula

=VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)

Comment: pls mark my answer as your solution if it helped you (mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). thanks

Answer (score 1):

Insert into the cell `G2` this formula and drag it down:

`=IF(VLOOKUP(B2;Sheet2!$A$2:$A$100;1;FALSE)=0;"";"G")`

Change `$A$2:$A$100` to your range in sheet2

Comment: katz,i tried to execute the formula you provided here but it popped a default formula error message saying "the formula you typed has an error"

Comment: @Iftekhar ensure that you have in both ranges the same datatype and check the formula by tipping it from beginning and then using the assistent